# OpenERP: How to hide some fields in Form View if no record found in many2many relationship?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Basic idea:
**Hide few fields in client form view for OpenERP users which are not defined as VIP users in my custom many2many table (user_id, partner_id)**

What I've already done:

**In res.partner form view:**

```
<field name="vip_ids" widget="many2many_tags" placeholder="VIP users..."/>
```

**My custom module which adds many2many relationship for res.partner module:**

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields
from osv import fields, osv
class res_partner_users_vip_rel2(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _description = "VIP status for partner (users)"
    _columns = {
        'vip_ids': fields.many2many(
            'res.users',
            'res_partner_users_vip_rel2',
            'partner_id',
            'users_id',
            'VIP status'),
    }
res_partner_users_vip_rel2()
```

In Form View I can successfully save multiple users in newly created field, but I am stuck at hiding other fields for users who are not defined in my many2many relationship.

As I understand, I need to use **attrs attribute** but I don't understand how to use it with many2many relationship.

This doesn't work:

```
<field name="mobile" attrs="{'invisible': [('uid','in', vip_ids)]}"/>
<field name="fax" attrs="{'invisible': [('uid','in', vip_ids)]}"/>
<field name="email" widget="email" attrs="{'invisible': [('uid','in', vip_ids)]}"/>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks OpenERP user aharoen for the answer:

http://help.openerp.com/question/38842/how-to-hide-some-fields-in-form-view-if-no-record-found-in-many2many-relationship/

View:

```
<record id="view_0001" model="ir.ui.view">  
<field name="name">XXXXXXX</field>
<field name="model">res.partner</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="XXXXXXXXXX" version="7.0">
        <group col="4" colspan="2">
            <field name="ids_count"/> 
            <field name="mobile" attrs="{'invisible': [('ids_count','=', 0)]}"/>
            <field name="fax" attrs="{'invisible': [('ids_count','=', 0)]}"/>
            <field name="email" widget="email" attrs="{'invisible': [('ids_count','=',0)]}"/> 
        </group>
        <field name="vip_ids"></field>

    </form> 
</field>
</record>
```

Controller:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
class res_partner_users_vip_rel2(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _description = "VIP status for partner (users)"
    def getcount(self, cr, uid,ids,name,arg,context):
        res={}
        sql="""
            SELECT partner_id id, count(*) cnt FROM res_partner_users_vip_rel2 
            WHERE partner_id = """+str(ids[0])+""" GROUP BY partner_id """
        cr.execute(sql)
        res.update(dict(cr.fetchall()))
        if res!={}:
            return res 
        return {ids[0]:0}
    _columns = {                
        'ids_count':fields.function(getcount,type="integer",string='Count'),

        'vip_ids': fields.many2many(
            'res.users',
            'res_partner_users_vip_rel2',
            'partner_id',
            'users_id',
            'VIP status'),
         }
```